# Simulate Excel LINEST behavior in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, curve-fitting

I need to emulate Excel LINEST function in MATLAB. The fit I am working on involves fitting a polynomial `y = a*x^3 + b*x + c` (No x^2) to 2 data points. I know it is mathematically unrealistic to fit a cubic polynomial to 2 data points. One would need at least 4 points to do it.

But, LINEST does return coefficients if I ask it to fit the cubic polynomial mentioned before. And for some reason, these coefficients match well with the physics of data I am trying to fit the curve to.

My question is how? And how can I get the same coefficients in a MATLAB script?
This is the exact LINEST formula I use: `=LINEST(AB47:AC47,AB46:AC46^{1;3},,TRUE)`

I created an example in the picture below:
[image]

Comment: I meant to say I had pasted wrong formula. I had pasted the full 4 column formula that's supposed to work in Excel and MATLAB polyfit works with 4 data points as well. Problem is with 2 data point case.

Comment: I believe the answer is that Excel is forcing one of the coefficients to be `0`.  It has an infinite number of choices though.  You get the same answer if you use `...^{3}` instead of `...^{1;3}`.  So to get MATLAB to return the same results as Excel, I would define it without the linear term and just use a cubic and a constant.

Comment: @Byron: Can you post an example MATLAB code?